# How to work with already installed application using appium?

Tags: java, android, appium

Precondition: Already installed the application in device via google play.

When I am trying to automate the already installed application in device, than each time it open the google browser instead of opening an application.

Can anyone let me know how can I open the application, I an new in appium.

Below is the code:

```
public class appium {
private static AndroidDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        File appDir = new File("D:/setup/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows/android-sdk-windows");
        File app = new File(appDir, "ab.java.programming-1.apk");
        System.out.println("app Dir.--->"+app);     

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        // Name of mobile web browser to automate. It should be an empty string, as we are automation an app
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        // Name of the OS: Android, iOS or FirefoxOS
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        // Device name:  – I am using Galaxy
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy");
        // Mobile OS version –  My device is running Android 4.4.4
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.4");
        // An absolute local path to the APK file
        //capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getCanonicalPath());

        // Java package of the tested Android app
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "ab.java.programming");

        // An activity name for the Android activity you want to run from your package.
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".MainActivity");

//       Constructor to initialize driver object with new Url and Capabilities
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.quit();

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set capabilities pointing to which or where the apk is.

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
```

And be sure to `CHECK` the `NO RESET` option in appium window so that it wont re install the apk.

EDIT:

Here is how i run an app located in my desktop.

```
        File app = new File("app location which is in the desktop"); //install
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); 

        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "LenovoB6000-HV");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "package name");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "Activity name");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        Thread.sleep(10000);//wait before closing the app
            driver.quit();
```

Comment: I have installed the .apk from google play and its saved on SDCard, well as you said I had set the capability of "getAbsolutePath()" and check the "No Rest" option from appium window. But whenever I am running the project first it install one build name "Unlock" and then open the chrome browser. But what what I need to do is "Open the application which is already being installed in device".

Comment: Wait for it to finish. the Unlock is a necessity for appium to run on your device. Have you waited for the appium logs to shutdown due to no new commands?

Comment: Yes, after completing the execution on appium window it generate the logs too. Also, quit the driver after completion. But application is not opening.

Comment: Well, If that's the case. I don't see anything wrong. The only thing i can't check is the location of your apk. Can you try placing it somewhere like your desktop?

Comment: My app location is: "Local storage/Device storage/Android/data", now can you please help me?

Comment: so its in the android device itself? I have never tried or even heard of that?   Can you try placing it in your desktop? Can I ask what app is it you try to test?

Comment: I am try to automate the "java programming" application. Also, if I am using it from desktop then how can I get the app package and app activity directly? because in device there are some application via that we can rectify it. It better that if you can help me with this too.

Comment: There is this app in the play store called APK info. It shows app package and activities of the installed apps in your device. Is it required that the insertion of your package and activity name to be automatic? What does that java programming app do? The only thing left to check is the application to be tested. I see no other factors why google chrome opens when you run your test.

Comment: I have already installed the "APK info" build and via that found the detail and "Java programming" is the learning application which I am trying to automate.

Comment: So are you able to run appium with the apk in your desktop?

Comment: No not able to run the apk which is in my desktop and not able to run with already installed application too. Firstly I am trying to automate the already installed application in device. Can you please share how can I do that or where I am going wrong in my code?